# Android client-server communication throws exception on input.read

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

i am developing Android-Server communication using sockets and input,output streams (no wrappign classes like datainputstream, objectinput stream etc.)

Communiction is based on three threads on each side (server has additional thread which accepts new socket)

1st thread is director, which accepts messages from receiver via LinkedBlockingQueue, reacts on them and sends data via LinkedBlockingQueue to sender

2nd thread is receiver which periodically reads socket (via InputStream.read) and if there is message it pass it to director with LinkedBlockingQueue

when connection is lost, Client-Android device (which has input.read blocked) throws immediately connection time out exception

3rd thread is sender which periodically takes messages from LinkedBlockingQueue and sends that data to other side of connection

Problem is: Prevent Exception on ClientSide receiver from throws (this look alike some Android thing, because input.read alone should not throw any exception related to time out connection

here is code of receiver:

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {

private boolean run = true;

BlockingQueue<MessageQueue> queueReceiverOut;

InputStream in;

////////////////////////////// CONSTRUCTOR ////////////////////////////////

public Receiver(BlockingQueue<MessageQueue> queueReceiverOut, InputStream in) {

    this.queueReceiverOut = queueReceiverOut;
    this.in = in;

}
// ////////////////////////////// METHODS ////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Runs when thread starts.
 */

public void run() {

    int[] message = new int[2];

    byte[] data;

    MessageQueue msg;

    try {

        while(true) {

            msg = new MessageQueue();

            message = receiveMessage();

            System.out.println("receives message");

            if(message[0] != -1) {

                System.out.println("receives full message");

                if(message[1] != 0) {

                    data = receiveData(message[1]);

                    msg.setMessageType(message[0]);
                    msg.setDataLength(message[1]);
                    msg.setData(data);

                    queueReceiverOut.put(msg);

                } else {

                    msg.setMessageType(message[0]);
                    msg.setDataLength(message[1]);
                    queueReceiverOut.put(msg);

                }
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("----disconnected-----");

        try {

            MessageQueue msgReceiverOut = new MessageQueue();

            msgReceiverOut.setMessageType(SocketMessages.STATUS_OFFLINE);
            queueReceiverOut.put(msgReceiverOut);

        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public int[] receiveMessage() throws IOException {

    int[] messageHead = new int[2];

    messageHead[0] = in.read();

    if(messageHead[0] != -1) {

        System.out.println("received message with type : " + messageHead[0]);

        int length1 = in.read();
        int length2 = in.read();
        int length3 = in.read();
        int length4 = in.read();

        messageHead[1] = ((length1 << 24) + (length2 << 16) + (length3 << 8) + (length4 << 0));

        System.out.println(" with length : " + messageHead[1]);

    }

    return messageHead;

}

public byte[] receiveData(int length) throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

     // Read in the bytes
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < length
    && (numRead = in.read(buffer,
    offset, length - offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
    }

    // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
    if (offset < length) {
    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file ");
    }

    return buffer;

}

public boolean isRun() {
    return run;
}

public void setRun(boolean run) {
    this.run = run;
}
```

}

and sender:

```
   public class Sender implements Runnable {

private boolean run = true;

BlockingQueue<MessageQueue> queueSenderIn;

BlockingQueue<MessageQueue> queueSenderOut;

OutputStream out;

////////////////////////////// CONSTRUCTOR ////////////////////////////////

public Sender(BlockingQueue<MessageQueue> queueSenderIn, BlockingQueue<MessageQueue> queueSenderOut, OutputStream out) {

    this.queueSenderOut = queueSenderOut;
    this.queueSenderIn = queueSenderIn;
    this.out = out;

}
// ////////////////////////////// METHODS ////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Runs when thread starts.
 */

@Override
public void run() {

    MessageQueue msg;

    try {

        while(run) {

            msg = queueSenderIn.poll(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            if(msg != null) {

                sendMessage(msg.getMessageType(),msg.getDataLength());

                if(msg.getDataLength()!=0) {

                    sendData(msg.getData());

                }

            }

        }

        Log.v(getClass().getName(),"sender destroyed");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getClass().getName(),"connection closed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public void sendMessage(int messageType, int dataLength) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    MessageQueue msg = new MessageQueue();

    Log.v(getClass().getName(), "sending message type : " + messageType);
    out.write(messageType);

    Log.v(getClass().getName(), "sending data with length : " +dataLength);

    out.write((dataLength >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    out.write((dataLength >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    out.write((dataLength >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((dataLength >>>  0) & 0xFF);

    msg.setMessageType(messageType);

    queueSenderOut.put(msg);

}

public void sendData(byte[] data) throws IOException {

    String string = new String(data,"UTF-8");

    Log.v(getClass().getName(), " with content : " + string);

    out.write(data);

}

public boolean isRun() {
    return run;
}

public void setRun(boolean run) {
    this.run = run;
}
```

}

UPDATED : Because misinterpreting exception

Comment: Do both sides send periodically? A `read` only thows IOExcpetion if the connection has already been lost when calling it. If it is lost while it is already blocking, it won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

> Under abnormal conditions the underlying connection may be broken by
>   the remote host or the network software (for example a connection
>   reset in the case of TCP connections). When a broken connection is
>   detected by the network software the following applies to the returned
>   input stream :
>
> - The network software may discard bytes that are buffered by the
>     socket. Bytes that aren't discarded by the network software can be
>     read using read.
> - If there are no bytes buffered on the socket, or all buffered bytes
>     have been consumed by read, then **all subsequent calls** to read will
>     throw an IOException.
> - If there are no bytes buffered on the socket, and the socket has not
>     been closed using close, then available will return 0.

from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()

Especially mind the "subsequent calls" part. That means if you are already blocking in a `read` call, the above condition regarding read calls does not (yet) apply.

So far the explanation. Now to the solution:
You can (one of many possibilities) periodically send messages, even when communication is idle. So your **sender** will detect connection loss and can close the in-stream, too.

---

EDIT: To make it a little bit clearer ...

1. Connection loss
2. call read
3. IOException

whereas

1. call read (blocks!)
2. waiting for input: connection lost
3. -- no Exception!

I guess the point is that ( I assume ) you server enters a read and stays there for a long time, while your client is receiving data while connection is broken. Thus it will constantly call and return from `read`. It still is possible that the connection loss is happening while waiting for a read to unblock, but it is much less probable.

Comment: Well from what i understand, if there is broken connection all subsequent calls to read (eg. server which has read on input) WILL throw an IOException. It works on clientside which has input.read all the time and when internet is turned off it throws io exception.. but server which has SAME thread (eg. reading from inputstream) doesn't throw anything, just hangs on read.

Comment: Does your server ever unblock from the read after the connection is lost? I guess not. So there is no "subsequent" call.

Comment: i'm pretty confused right now.. server receiver and client receiver are same coded classes with same methods, but one throws exception and the other not, can you be please more specific?

Comment: Get it now, sorry for that. Its not exactly IOexception, but SSLException which is thrown, but client receiver react on it as it was IOException, but server isn't..

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of that? I recommend updating your question, then. I'll delete the answer, since it is senseless then.